# Presenting a modal view controller over only one half of a split view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller, ipad

I'm adapting an existing iPhone app to run on the iPad. In the iPhone version, when the user tapped a toolbar button, I would present a modal view controller with a `modalTransitionStyle` of `UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal`, which made a really nice "card-flipping" animation.

The iPad interface is based on a split view (`MGSplitViewController`, actually). The toolbar button is on the detail pane, so when I present the modal view controller, it takes up the entire screen and the flip transition makes no sense.

To get the right user interaction, I'd like the modal controller to appear and flip into place *only* over the detail view controller, leaving the master view controller as is.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @parilogic Unfortunately, that's what I'm doing already: i.e. I'm presenting from the split view controller. The modal controller still covers the whole screen.

Comment: Um wait.You have to present it through DetailViewController's instance.

Comment: Neither works. I've tried both the split view controller and the detail view controller. Both take up the entire screen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;

[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I actually ended up using this solution and abandoning the flip. Thanks!

Comment: The presentation style varies based on whether you're running iOS 7 or iOS 8: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242286

Answer (score 5):

Probably you can just add its view as as a subview of DetailViewcontroller and use UIview animation to make it look like modal. [Reference to `[UIView transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:)

**EDIT**
When watching WWDC2010 Video (Session 123 : Building Animation Driven Interfaces), I accidentally came to know that I can do the same transition in different manner. I sample coded and it worked :)

It is to use another very similar API [`[UIView transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:)

My sample code is as follows

```
// Within your DetailViewController
[self.view addSubview:self.flipSideView];
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:0.8 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^{} completion:nil];
```

Yup, that was it. Just add the flip side view as a subview and use `transitionWithView:...` animation instead of `transitionFromView...`.

Comment: This sounds promising. Let me give that a try.

Comment: Same thing - the modal view controller seems to always expand to take up the whole screen. It's wrapped in a navigation controller, BTW, but I need the nav controller.

Comment: It seems like UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft is the problem - even if I resize the nav controller, the entire screen flips - not just the details controller.

Comment: Hello @Bill, I am not sure if you are still tracking this issue, but I just came up with a working answer and edited my answer accordingly.