# Layout issues when presenting a view controller with UIModalPresentationStyleCurrentContext

Tags: ios, ipad, swift, uisplitviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I ran into a problem having to do with `UISplitViewController` and modal view controllers on the iPad, so I tried to reproduce the issue in a small project to see if I could figure out what was going on. Unfortunately, the problem seems to still be occurring, but I can't figure out why.

I've included a very small, complete Swift program below that reproduces the problem. Basically, if you run that code in a new Swift iOS project on the iPad, you'll see the following behavior:

The app will start with the following UI:

[image]

If I tap Present, a new modal controller will present over the detail side of the split controller. If I tap Dismiss on that modal controller, I'll return to the same initial interface and all is well.

However, if I tap Present, then tap Present on the modal controller that appears (so I have two modal controllers over the original details view), and then dismiss the top one, the `RightViewController` takes over the entire screen, eliminating the split view controller:

[image]

I've been banging my head against this all afternoon. Is there something I'm missing?

Here is the complete source for the example application:

```
import UIKit

class RightController: UIViewController {
    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        self.title = "Right"
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 100, height: 20))
        label.text = "Top Left"
        self.view.addSubview(label)

        let presButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Present", style: .Plain, target: self, action: Selector("present:"))

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = presButton
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Dismiss", style: .Plain, target: self, action: Selector("dismiss:"))
    }

    func dismiss(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func present(sender: AnyObject) {
        let rc = RightController()
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rc)
        nav.modalPresentationStyle = .CurrentContext
        self.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        let splitViewController = UISplitViewController()
        splitViewController.delegate = self

        let nav1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: UIViewController())
        nav1.title = "Left"

        let nav2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: RightController())

        splitViewController.viewControllers = [nav1, nav2]
        self.window!.rootViewController = splitViewController

        return true
    }
}

extension AppDelegate: UISplitViewControllerDelegate {
    func splitViewController(svc: UISplitViewController, shouldHideViewController vc: UIViewController, inOrientation orientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Cycling through the device's orientations causes the split view controller to redraw itself correctly, at least until Dismiss is pressed again.

**EDIT**: I can also get this to work if I use the new `.OverCurrentContext` presentation style in iOS 8. However, I can't drop compatibility with iOS 7, so I need a different solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a solution that works although I will be the first to admit, it does feel a little hacky. I think a big part of your issue stems from a change in `.CurrentContext` and after some testing I found that it functions differently for iOS 7 and 8+. So everything works expectedly if you choose the proper style based on the iOS version:

```
var presStyle: UIModalPresentationStyle = (UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion as NSString).integerValue == 7 ? .CurrentContext : .OverCurrentContext
nav.modalPresentationStyle = presStyle
```

Comment: This seems to work! You're right - it looks like the meaning of .CurrentContext has changed between operating systems. I'll test this out in depth later today but right now it does seem to solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Bill, glad it works. Yeah, an odd change. Let me know if you have any further problems with this.